# SVN - Always ignore externals when performing an svn up

Tags: svn, command-line-interface

I have several client repositories that share an external.

Occasionally when I haven't had enough coffee, I lazily do an

```
svn up
```

forgetting to add --ignore-externals and proceed to checkout the entire core of the system into my clients repository.

Is there a way I can always ignore externals by default? As I can't see a use case for it and repeatedly removing the projects jsut to check them out again without the externals is rather long-winded.

I was thinking I could alias svn up to svn up --ignore-externals but I'm not sure where to begin with this, or if there is a more suitable approach like a preferences / config file I can edit.

Comment: There is no inherent problem with aliasing `svn up` to `svn up --ignore-externals`, in common shells like `bash`. The problem comes when you *don't* want to ignore externals, as `svn` is not smart enough to take a `--no-externals` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no official/documented way to achieve this, but there are some workarounds with bash scripts that will modify default svn commands so when you type svn up, script will add --ignore-externals option.

Try this: [workaround 1](http://www.dotevan.com/2008/11/08/de-annoyifying-subversion-externals/),
[workaround 2](http://techcribsheet.blogspot.com/2013/06/netbeans-svn-ignore-externals-workaround.html)

Hope it helps !